# CMD - How to list text files that inside contain some words

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, search

If in windows there is a folder with several files, say c:/folder with files and inside it has random name files.

And I have a .txt file with several words, say c:/words/wordstofind.txt

I would like to know if there is a way that pc can enter check if any of the words in wordstofind.txt exist inside each of the files in c:/folder with files, and if at least 1 exist, then give me the filenames of those files within that folder that do contain any of the words in wordstofind.txt

I dont need to know which word it found, and also if it finds any word, it can add the filename of that file to result directly and pass to searching the next file within the folder (1 result is enought to go to the result file).

Result file to be saved into C:/results/resultfilenames.txt

When I open the resultfilenames.txt, it should contain only the name of the files that contain any of those words specified, not the folder if possible (whch would be the same for all).

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible. It's clear you want a command line solution but do you have a preference regarding implementation (e.g. Batch, PowerShell, any scripting language)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes, I would like to do it in windows CMD. I just found this command below makes the job however its result is showing the folder/filename.txt in the result file (only need the filename.txt).Also, when I added /I to it (before the /S) it is not disconsidering the case of the letters (example: if I put in wordstosearch.txt file the word "hello", i need it to find either "Hello" or "hello" or "HeLlo" or etc ways upper or lower case not mattering). Would you know how to fix this? Thanks
Formula: FINDSTR /S /g:wordstosearch.txt /f:listoffilestosearch.txt > result.txt

Comment: Hello, about the case seems is working like this now. However, I am doing the same test many times, and sometimes it gives the correct result and sometimes it doesnt give the result that should be there. How accurate is this findstr? Is there another way to do this very accurately in windows? if so, could you explain how, this is, do i need to download any plugin and how to use it for this purpose? thanks

Comment: When the file contains lots of texts big sizes with blanks, spaces, empty lines, symbols etc, is where it is failing to search the words. Should I add another command so it can read this well? Thanks

Comment: I copied this exact page in here into a file and asked to search some words in here and it doesnt find anything, as example.

Comment: `findstr` has a [bunch of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/3395469). At a guess, your varying results may be due to trying to find multiple literal search strings.

Comment: Hello, ok, what would be the grep commands for them via command line?Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer regarding grep.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you have everything working now. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a native Windows solution, [FINDSTR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) is a possible option. For your use case, you could try:

```
findstr /l /s /i /m /g:searchwords.txt /f:filestosearch.txt > results.txt
```

This tells FINDSTR to (respectively):

- Use the search words as string literals (rather than regular expressions).
- Recurse sub-folders.
- Ignore case sensitivity.
- Print only file names (which happens to include the full directory path).

Note, however, FINDSTR has [undocumented limits and bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) which may not make it a suitable option.

For a non-native solution, you might be interested in a port of the [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) utility, such as [GNUWin32 grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). While grep implementations can vary in the options they support, GNUWin32 grep is a port of [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) (albeit currently v2.5.4 rather than v3.0) which can read search terms from a file. For your use case, you can try:

```
grep -rilf C:\path\to\searchwords.txt C:\path\to\search > results.txt
```

This tells grep to (respectively):

- Recurse sub-folders.
- Ignore case sensitivity.
- Suppress normal output (list files only, including full path).
- Pull search terms from a text file.

Both FINDSTR and grep return full paths to a file, so you will likely need to do additional processing on the output of either. Be aware, however, that unlike FINDSTR, grep options are typically case-sensitive. For instance, -L is *not* the same option as -l (lowercase L). Any paths with spaces require double quotes ("") as normal.

If you wish to search only specific files, you can list them on the command line individually (e.g. `doc1.txt doc2.txt doc3.txt`) in place of the directory. You can use full paths (e.g.`C:\path\to\doc1.txt`) as necessary.

It's also worth mentioning that the reason I have placed the "searchwords.txt" file in a separate directory is that GNUWin32 grep will include this file in the "matched" items otherwise.

Finally, while it shouldn't be a deal-breaker in most instances, GNUWin32 grep uses Unix-style line feeds for its output, as well as a mix of `\` and `/` for paths.

*Note that there is some additional explanation of these last two GNUWin32 grep specific quirks at end of this answer... so you may wish to read that as well. =)*

**Fixing Output With sed**

Since you want just the file names, we can actually use another GNUWin32 utility called [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to obtain these. This is a port of [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), a "non-interactive command-line text editor". What this means is that this program can take text input from the command line, modify it in a standardized way, and output that modified data.

In our case with GNUWin32 grep, we can use it to eliminate everything before each file name with:

```
sed s/.\+[/+]//
```

Furthermore, we can pipe `|` the output from grep to sed like so:

```
grep -rilf C:\path\to\searchwords.txt C:\path\to\search | sed s/.\+[/+]// > results.txt
```

This will leave just the file name in "results.txt" and has the added benefit of eliminating any issues with `/` and Unix-style line feeds (all `/` are removed and, at least when piping like this, sed outputs normal Windows line breaks).

The breakdown of the sed command is as follows:

- `s/` is the beginning of the substitute command.
- `.\+[/+]` is a regular expression (what we want to find -- in this case everything up to and including the last `/` in our grep output).
- `//` is, respectively, the required `/` separator between our item to find and our replacement, no space (a blank replacement) and the final `/` required for all sed substitute commands.
- sed can also us other separators e.g. + in case of conflicts (say, with directory slashes).
- A missing final `/` will result in an "unterminated 's' command" error.

As a small caveat, the sed command above eliminates sub-directory information as well, so the file names returned may not all be in the same (root) directory.

You can read more about GNU sed regular expressions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

---

**GNUWin32 grep Quirks**

*Newlines*

[Newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) are normally hidden control characters in a text document which signal to an application where to separate lines of text. Importantly, these can vary from operating system to operating system.

In the case of [Unix-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems (where grep originated), this is a simple Line Feed, represented as `/n` e.g.

```
line 1 /n
line 2 /n
```

Windows is similar but uses an additional Carriage Return, represented as `/r`, before its Line Feed. This results in a combined `/r/n` rather than just `/n`.

While not usually an issue, some Windows programs (such as Windows Notepad) behave differently with single Line Feeds (`/n`). One common issue is making lines run together e.g.

```
line1line2
```

Since GNUWin32 grep produces `/n` control characters only and not `/r/n`, this can cause output sent to a file (via ">" above) to have readability or other issues in some instances. If necessary, this can be fixed by either replacing the `/n` control characters with `/r/n` (possible through additional scripting) or by simply using a program that supports reading/replacing these characters (such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).

*Reversed Separators*

Another inherited quirk is the difference in the separators used for directories (paths) between Unix-style and Windows systems. On Unix-style systems, the separators are forward slashes e.g.

```
/path/to/some/file.txt
```

Windows, however, uses backwards slashes e.g.

```
C:\path\to\some\directory
```

GNUWin32 grep oddly combines the two, using the normal backwards slashes for the primary directory path and forward slashes for listing file matching results e.g.

```
C:\path\to\some\directory/match1.txt
C:\path\to\some\directory/subdirectory/match2.txt
```

This quirk can be overcome with (again) additional scripting or a simple Find/Replace in any normal text editor.